# Questions about Hensel's lemma.

Tags: p-adic-number-theory, hensels-lemma

I was reading through Hensel's lemma, highlighted [here](http://math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/REU2018/REUPapers/Chen,Yuchen.pdf) on page $8$ and had a couple of queries:

- In the proof when the author wants  to show that $f(\alpha)=0$; it says something like "since $f(a_n)\equiv 0\bmod p^n$, we have that $\vert f(a_n)\vert_p\leq1/p^n$. Why is this the case? I'm not too sure as to where that's come from.
- Also suppose we wish to find a $3$-adic expansion of $\sqrt{-1}$. Looking at $x^2+1\equiv 0\bmod 3$, we see that this has no roots. Does this mean that $\sqrt{-1}\in\Bbb Z_3$ because there are no roots?
- In a similar token, suppose we wish to find a $5$-adic expansion of $\sqrt{-1}$. Then $x^2+1\equiv 0\bmod 5$ has roots and can be lifted as the derivative is non-zero at both roots. Then what does the $5$-adic expansion start with? In other words, in the power series representation, what would the "$5^0$ term" be?
- Finally, is my notation right? Like does Hensel's lemma look at $\Bbb Z_p$ or $\Bbb Q_p$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $5$-adic expansion of $\sqrt{-1}$ starts with $2$ or $3$

Comment: As for the second point, it means there is *no* root of $-1$ in the $3$-adics.

Comment: J.W.Tanner so does the expansion start with $2+5x+25y+...$ or $5(2)+25y+...$ where $x$ and $y$ are the coefficients to be found by the lifting? Also, Torsten Schoeneberg, thank you!

Comment: it starts with $2+5x+25y+\cdots$

Comment: Brilliant, that's what I would've gone for too - thanks!